# Symfony 3 uploading files with curl

Tags: php, curl, upload, symfony

This is somewhat noob question, but I am stuck for two days with it. I want to upload a file to Symfony and I want to do it with curl. File won't be renamed, only moved to the appropriate folder (file names are already unique). Symfony doesn't need to to any checks whatsoever and nothing will be persisted to database (I've already taken care of authentication and authorization). I don't want to use VichUploaderBundle.

I've read the official tutorial, as well as many others, but they are focused on making this work when uploading from browser, storing file info in database, etc. I don't need any of that.

I guess that I should somehow capture file in the Controller and move it from temporary location to where I want it, but I can't figure out how to do this. So, how to make Symfony accept file in POST or PUT request and copy it to a directory of my choice?

EDIT:
It's possible to use native PHP for this, but is there a better way?